# getting Restangular nested resources

Tags: angularjs, filter, resources, nested, restangular

so... I want to get the nested resources of a parent resource.

I want to show all the PAGES of a certain BOOK.

It would be nice to do it with restangular somehow.  It seems like I ought to be able to when I look at the docs. Here is a hack I've made in angularJS that works, but I feel like I should be making this happen with Restangular:

```
$scope.getPages = () ->
      Restangular.one('books', 8).getList('pages').then (response) ->
        console.log(response)
        $scope.pages = $filter('filter')(response, book_id: 8)
```

`Restangular.one('books', 8).getList('pages')` returns ALL the pages from ALL the books.  I don't get that.... shouldn't it return just the pages from book 8?

Anyway, from there I'm just filtering the pages so I only end up with the pages from book 8.

But can't I do this with Restangular somehow?

PS, There are no examples I've found that use the $filter from AngularJS in a js file like this... everything is done through HTML like "page in pages | filter: {book_id: 8}"

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem..?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is a little wrong so the wrong request is probably being sent. Try:

```
Restangular.one('books', 8).all('pages').getList().then(response)
```

This should make a request to: `/books/8/pages`

Comment: Thanks!!  In reality.. both of those syntaxes make the right GET request.  I had my rails Controller giving back Book.all  instead of Book.find(params[:id]).  As a side note... if I wanted to make a GET request for pages that belonged to a book... I would say @pages = Page.where(book_id: params[:book_id]) and not Page.where(book_id: params[:id]).  So really, my problem was getting Angular to talk to rails correctly

Comment: @user3583384 The syntax is definitely not correct and both of these will not make the same `GET` request. The `getList('pages')` in your question is incorrect, only query params should go in the `get` and `getList` parts of the builder. What you have in your question will make a request to `books/8`.